# image crud need to add validation for fixed size image upload e.g. 600 x 800 only

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing, grocery-crud

i am trying to add fixed height width image validation in image crud class but not succeded in it. tried below but not worked. image not uploaded but database entry done.

```
class ImageUploadHandler
{

========

private function has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error) {



if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($uploaded_file);

if($width != 600 || $height != 800){

return 'maxFileSize';

}

        } else {
            $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
        }



}
```

NOTE : Code working fine. but error should send to client side. i think it is not handled in image-crud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got succeeded into adding validation for fixed size image.(as in question i am on right track, but below code worked).

In image_crud.php class line no. 333.

```
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
 if($width != $this->max_width || $height != $this->max_height)
 {                 
 /* Commented below line */         
  //$ci->image_moo->load($path)->resize($this->max_width,$this->max_height)->save($path,true);
    //and returned false
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a parenthesis in your code that souldn't be there... right under `return 'masFileSize'`

Answer (score 0):

Change this one

```
if($width != 600 || $height != 800){

return 'maxFileSize';

}
```

to

```
if($width > 600 || $height > 800){

return 'maxFileSize';

}
```